# Diagrama de Sankey y base de datos de Transacciones R

Tags: r, transacciones

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un dataset de Ventas de una tienda de Ropa. Esta contiene todas las transacciones realizadas desde el 2019 a la fecha.

El formato en que están los datos es el siguiente:

```
 ID | OrderId | Items | Categoria | Precio  | N° Boleta |                    
  1    ABC        2      Polera     10.000       1
  1    ABC        2      Pantalón    9.000       1
  1    ABD        1      Polera     10.000       2
  1    ABE        3      Polera     10.000       3
  1    ABE        3      Pantalón    9.000       3
  1    ABE        3      Zapatos    15.000       3
  2    XYZ        2      Polera     10.000       1
  2    XYZ        2      Pantalón    9.000       1
  2    XYO        1      Chaqueta   10.000       2
  2    XYU        3      Polera     10.000       3
  2    XYU        3      Pantalón    9.000       3
  2    XYU        3      Zapatos    15.000       3
```

Actualmente para realizar un diagrama de Sankey estoy considerando el **Precio** mas alto de la transacción (OrderId) para clasificar la venta por categoria, de la siguiente forma.

```
ID  | N° Boleta | Categoria 
 1        1        Polera
 1        2        Polera
 1        3        Zapatos
 2        1        Polera
 2        2        Chaqueta
 2        3        Zapatos
```

Y finalmente uso la función spread para crear una "matriz" con el ID del cliente y cada columna corresponde al N° de Boleta con su respectiva Categoria

```
ID  |  N° Boleta 1 | N° Boleta 2 | N° Boleta 3 |
1       Polera        Polera         Zapatos
2       Polera        Chaquetas      Zapatos
```

Finalmente realizo un group by para por ID, N° Boleta 1, N° Boleta 2, N° Boleta 3 para calcular la cantidad de repeticiones que tienen todas las conbinaciones posibles para finalmente gráficar con el siguiente código.

```
alluvial( Dataset[,1:3], freq=Dataset$Freq, border=NA )
```

Hasta el momento eso me ha funcionado de forma correcta con el siguiente gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es la siguiente, ¿es **correcto** realizar un diagrama de Sankey pero utilizando todas las Categorías de las transacciones?

De no ser correcto, ¿que alternativas existen para graficar el proceso de compra de los clientes?

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: No sé cuantas categorías son todas, pero si son muchas las sankey plots se hacen muy difíciles de entender visualmente. De hecho en el ejemplo no es tan clara cuál es la idea que trasmite el gráfico. Tomando ese gráfico como base se me ocurren dos ideas para dar más inteligibilidad al gráfico: 1) compactar las categorías minoritarias en "Otro" o algo por estilo , 2) usar alguna clave de color para destacar lo que te interesa (alguna trayectoria en especial). `ggalluvial` permite usar colores, seguramente la librería que usas también.

Comment: Otra alternativa es trabajarlo directamente con un enfoque de análisis de redes. Si te interesan, por ejemplo, trayectorias típicas o trayectorias similares/disimilares hay algoritmos específicamente para eso. La librería `tidygraph` tiene un interface "tidy" bastante fácil de usar e implementa algunos algoritmos para grafos direccionales. En https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/index.html hay información básica sobre los algoritmos disponibles.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! La idea del Sankey es mostrar que compran los clientes en su primera, segunda y tercera compra (si es que han comprado 3 veces claramente).  La idea es determinar si un cliente compra una polera, lo mas probable es que en su segunda compra, compre nuevamente una polera o pantalón. Sobre la estética del gráfico, esta la hago en Power Bi que es por donde envió el informe al cliente.

Comment: Coincido plenamente con mpaladino, reducir todo a 4 categorias y agregar colores va a mejorar mucho la comprensión de la gráfica. También puedes probar como se ve todo con un  diagrama de cuerdas tipo: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/229-several-circular-plots-in-a-figure.html